# C++ Class with member varialble vector <another class>

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have an assignment to make Information system about resorts in a country, be able to read/write data for the resorts from/to file and modifying it.

```
class CTоurist{
    string m_StrName;
    string m_StrCountry;
    int m_iAge;
public:
    //constructors, mutators, accessors overloading operator <<,>>

};
```

I don't have problem writing this class. And here I have class which contains as member variable vector of the first class's objects

```
class CHotel
{
    string m_strHotelName;
    int m_iNumberOfBets;
    double m_dAveragePrice; //average price per bet in the hotel
    vector <CTourist> m_vecTourists; //vector of tourists rested in the hotel
public:
.....
};
```

And one more class Resort containing as member variable vector of the second class's objects

```
class CResort
{
    string m_ResortName;
    unsigned m_Height;
    vector<CHotel*> m_Hotels;
public:
.....
};
```

So here is the problem. I'm not sure how to write the accessor,mutator and constructors for that vector variable so I can use them property. Thank you for checking and if someone could help me figure out these functions I'll be really grateful!

Comment: Why a vector of `CHotel*` and not `CHotel`?

Comment: well that's how the assignment is (being more harder to be done I guess :) ), but anyways I haven't got yet to that point so I consider it as vector <CHotel> currently

Comment: It really depends on what `CResort` and `CHotel` are supposed to do. You should start with their public interface, and only see the vectors as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly you want to know the best way to get your hotels from cResort.

i would recommend

```
cHotel* GetHotelByName(std::string& a_sName)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_Hotels.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_Hotel[i].GetName() == a_sName)
            return m_Hotel[i]
    }
return nullptr; // if non found return return null
}
```

and add a GetName function to your hotel class which returns a string of its name. 
this also allows you to SetName etc.

Answer (score 1):

1) Accessor, mutator: There are plenty of options.

You can create another class like `CTouristList` (and `CHotelList` respectively), that wraps the `vector`, have it referenced from the `CHotel` class (accessor methods like `CTouristList& CHotel::GetTouristList()` and `const CTouristList& CHotel::GetTouristList() const`) and implement methods like `CTouristList::Add`, `CTouristList::Remove`, `CTouristList::Get`, etc.

Or you can add methods like `CHotel::AddTourist()` directly on the `CHotel` class.

2) Constructor. Nothing needed in constructor. But for `vector<CHotel*>` you may need destructor in `CResort` to explicitly free the `CHotel` instances. Though not sure why you want to use pointers to `CHotel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the accessor and mutator functions in CTourist just like you would if they were not being stored in a Vector.

To utilize them once they are in CHotel you could add a function in CHotel that returns a pointer to a CTourist.

```
// Access a CTourist
Hotel.getTourist(1)->setName("Tourist name");
```

Adding a method that returns the number of tourist that visited a hotel would make it easier to loop through them.

```
for(int i = o; i < Hotel.touristCount(); ++i)
{
  // Do something useful
  std:: cout << "Hello " << Hotel.getTourist(i)->getName();
}
```

In that case your CHotel::touristCount() would be a wrapper around the vector<>.size();

If you do not want code outside of CHotel to have direct access to a CTourist object then create wrapper functions in CHotel that do what you would want to do externally.

i.e.
    std::cout << Hotel.getTouristName(1);

instead of

std::cout << Hotel.getTourist(1)->getName();

Comment: Please use iterators; its more idiomatic and imho more readable.

Comment: I agree. However I think it would add more complication then necessary to this example by requiring another wrapper method in CHotel that returns an iterator for the storage type currently used and the auto keyword so he could change the storage mechanism later. Again I agree with you, on using iterators, but this example seems more clear without them.